# Help making Fluent NHibernate create an oracle sequence for each table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I am using Fluent NHibernate's (1.0 RTM) automapping feature to create my oracle database schema. My issue is that all the tables are using a single "hibernate-sequence", whereas I would prefer (and my boss would demand) a sequence generator for each table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed to solve my own solution. Here's the code:

```
public class OraclePrimaryKeySequenceConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.GeneratedBy.Sequence(string.Format("Sequence_{0}",
                                                    instance.EntityType.Name));
    }
}
```

Yay. :-)

Comment: Been a while, but how would I use this?